# No usefull backtrace with gdb on ARM

Tags: c++, gdb, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to debug a simple application on an embedded platform (gateworks cambria, arm). I'm using a cross compiled gdb on the target platform. However when the application crashes due to a segfault i do not get the bt i'm accustomed to on my pc. I've tried to simplify the process and this is the complete gdb output:

```
dlopen failed on 'libthread_db.so.1' - File not found
GDB will not be able to debug pthreads.

GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "armeb-openwrt-linux"...
(no debugging symbols found)
(gdb) run /tmp/empower.aligned.click 
Starting program: /usr/bin/click /tmp/empower.aligned.click
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
(no debugging symbols found)
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.1
(no debugging symbols found)
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(no debugging symbols found)
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /lib/libm.so.0
(no debugging symbols found)
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
(no debugging symbols found)
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file /lib/libc.so.0
(no debugging symbols found)
/tmp/empower.click:20: While initializing 'FromDevice@13 :: FromDevice':
  warning: moni0: no IPv4 address assigned
ctrl :: Socket: opened connection 8 to 192.168.1.132:4000
el :: EmpowerLVAPManager :: compute_bssid_mask :: FF:F1:21:32:0C:BA
expensive Packet::push; have 28 wanted 30
expensive Packet::push; have 28 wanted 30
expensive Packet::push; have 28 wanted 30
expensive Packet::push; have 28 wanted 30
expensive Packet::push; have 28 wanted 30

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6e0398c in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6e0398c in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x52429a3c
```

Comment: It's saying `(no debugging symbols found)`. Are you using the compiler option for compiling with debug information?

Comment: More likely as this is a cross-compiled `gdb` it doesn't know where to find the target's symbols (or they weren't generated in the first place).

Comment: `set solib-absolute-prefix`.  There is a process to detach the debug information.  `objcopy --only-keep-debug original debug` and `strip original` and `objcopy--add-gnu-debuglink=debug original`, where *original* is the binary with debug strip and *debug* is a file with only debug information.  You need this debug information on your *hosted* **gdb** so that it can interpret addresses and give a back trace.  Note, on the ARM some code compilation options may prohibit back traces.  All depends on the tool chain.  You are not in **PC land** any more; getting this right is **book like**.

Comment: Perhaps your stack pointer got corrupted and is pointing to something unrelated ("Cannot access memory at address 0x52429a3c"). Could be a buffer overflow or you've overwritten R13 somehow.